# Use a LinearGradientBrush in another LinearGradientBrush?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, colors, color-space

I'm trying to use one LinearGradientBrush in the Definition of another LinearGradientBrush. But I've no idea weather this would even work, and if it works, I need to know how.

For Example:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDEEB3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBF2CD" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCE48A" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBE388" Offset="0.75"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FilterPopupTitleBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#B45988" Offset="0.75"/>
        //Code here to use ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush
        <GradientStop Color="#990088" Offset="0.75"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

thanking you in anticipation for your answers

Edit:
To get things a bit more clear in the example I want to use "ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush" in the "FilterPopupTitleBrush" as a "template".So that I've the same color gradient in both brushes without a copy of the "<GradientStop...>"-tags

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can share the list of gradient stops between multiple brushes, like this:-

```
<GradientStopCollection x:Key="MyGradient">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFDEEB3" Offset="0"/> 
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFBF2CD" Offset="1"/> 
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCE48A" Offset="0.5"/> 
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFBE388" Offset="0.75"/> 
</LinearGradientBrush> 

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0"
   GradientStops="StaticResource MyGradient}" /> 

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FilterPopupTitleBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0"
    GradientStops="{StaticResource MyGradient}" />
```

Now you can vary the `EndPoint`, `StartPoint` and other properties create different variants of the same basic gradient.

You can even supply the same set to `RadialGradientBrush`.

Comment: When I'm trying to define a GradientStopCollection in a Silverlight 4 ResourceDictionary I get a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error, any idea why?

Comment: Same here with Silverlight 5. Found it programmatically first and then tried with this XAML markup and got the same.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing another way of doing this, you don't need to create a separate collection, you can also reuse the existing brush like

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FilterPopupTitleBrush" GradientStops="{Binding GradientStops, Source={StaticResource ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush}}"/>
```

This way of creating a custom brush based on existing brush will be helpful specially when you want to extend predefined themes like `Telerik` themes, where it would not be good approach to change the `XAML` from telerik.